# Suppress tempdb message when outputting result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

Using `SQLCMD`, I am running a script to output to `STDOUT` then gziping the output.  When I look at the output file, I see this warning message:

`Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.`

In my script, I have a check at the start of the script to drop the temp table if it exists:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TheTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE tempdb..#TheTable
END
```

However - I have also `SET NOCOUNT ON`, but file still captures the warning message.

SQLCMD Script:
`sqlcmd -i TheScript.sql -h-1 -k1 -s"," -W -u | gzip > "C:\TheOutput.gz"`

Is there a way to suppress a message like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if condition to the following pattern:

```
IF 0 < OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TheTable')
 DROP TABLE #TheTable
```

This should not result in any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Simple clean version that works on SQL Server 2016 and above without any messages:

```
drop table if exists #TheTable
```